# How the XmlReader works in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I'm trying to read some Xml from a string I made, but really any Xml file would be ok.

I just want to browse the Xml nodes like it's a multidimensional matrix and eventually put them in a DataTable (to put them in a sql server with SqlBulkCopy). I've already looked in MSDN and around here. Could someone explain it plain and simple please?

This is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        private static DataTable table = new DataTable();
        private static String xmlString =
        @"<?xml version='1.0'?>
        <!-- This is a sample XML document -->
        <Garage>
            <Car>
                <Name>Ferrari</Name>
                <Speed>360km/h</Speed>
                <Engine>Ferrari Enzo</Engine>
                <Color>Red</Color>
                <Year>1999</Year>
            </Car>
            <Car>
                <Name>Maserati</Name>
                <Speed>270km/h</Speed>
                <Color>Metal Grey</Color>
                <Year>2007</Year>
            </Car>
            <Car>
                <Name>Limo</Name>
                <Color>Black</Color>
                <Engine>Chevrolet</Engine>
                <Year>2007</Year>
            </Car>
        </Garage>";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program x = new Program();
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlString));
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(XmlNodeType.Element.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

I would like to loop the whole thing and get something like:

Name: Ferrari
Speed: 360km/h
Engine: Ferrari Enzo

and so on, you got the drill.

Comment: `XmlReader` is a forward-only-read-only reader of XML nodes. That's not what you want, so don't use it for that.

Comment: I like how people unlike this for no reason.

Whatever, What should I use instead?

Comment: They "downvote" because you put no effort into your question. The answer is given below.

Comment: If that would mean something, your downvote would be useful to the community.

Nowadays you get downvoted for asking on a programming questions site, lol. It's since this morning that I'm trying to read, document and learn about this pile of steaming brown matter that microsoft wrote (like 9 hours I guess) and I still can't get anything out of it. But you prefere to downvote and say "no effort".

Thank you. And thank that this site is modded. Lot of bad words would be coming on you.

The same applies to the egomaniac mods editing every possible question even for no reason.

Comment: Please read the [faq] and learn where you're posting before you post. You are not making a good impression.

Comment: Well, I perfectly know that this is a polite place where you gotta behave. But to ask for politness someone should behave the same way. And I'm not just ranting randomly because I can't parse my XML today.
I'm talking of events happened earlier in time and more than one time, to me and to other people. So I'll take the risk, but I'll say what it has to be said, as I'm not saying any lie.

Funnily enough, various users agreed with my opinions. I won't enter in details, just wanted you to know that. Didn't mean to offend or bother people who visit this site with a constructive attitude.

Comment: You haven't read the [faq], have you? Maybe try reading [ask] as well. This isn't the sort of place you seem to think it is.

Comment: Already read some time ago:

-thoroughly searched for an answer--->DONE, found everything confusing and not clear. Otherwise I wouldn't had asked.

-Be specific
It doesn't seems to me that asking how XmlReader can be put in a multidimensional matrix/datatable fashion is like asking "Hey what can I do with a class?"

Be on-topic
That wasn't a question about Picasso. There is code, there is a problem. And all the "Asking FAQ" points too.

Keep an open mind

Accepted all the answers. Not accepted yours (and someone else who removed it) downvote, which, after what I said, is for no reason.

Peace

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345532.aspx) will give you an `XDocument`.  `XDocument.Root` will get you the root `XElement` of your document. I think you'll find this very easy to work with.

You're trying to use the previous generation of XML tools in .NET - the newer `XDocument`, `XElement`, etc tools are much more accessible.

---

## sample code

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
...
var root = XDocument.Parse(xmlString).Root;

var cars = root
    .ToAll("Car")
    .Select(car => new
    {
        Name = car.ToFirst("Name").Value,
        Speed = car.ToAll("Speed").Any() ? car.ToFirst("Speed").Value : null,
        Color = car.ToFirst("Color").Value,
        Engine = car.ToFirst("Engine").Value,
        Year = int.Parse(car.ToFirst("Year").Value)
    })
    .ToList();
```

---

## helper class

```
public static class XmlHelper
{
    public static XNode ReadFrom(Stream stream)
    {
        using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
            return XDocument.Load(xmlReader);
    }

    public static void WriteTo(Stream stream, XNode node)
    {
        using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream))
            node.WriteTo(xmlWriter);
    }

    public static XElement ToFirst(this XElement ancestor, String descendantLocalName)
    {
        return ancestor.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(element => element.Name.LocalName == descendantLocalName);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<XElement> ToAll(this XElement ancestor, String descendantLocalName)
    {
        return ancestor.Descendants().Where(element => element.Name.LocalName == descendantLocalName);
    }

    public static string ToAttribute(this XElement element, string name)
    {
        var attribute = element.Attribute(XName.Get(name));
        return attribute != null ? attribute.Value : null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ugh, this syntax is even worse because I have no idea of what LINQ is or how it works so I wouldn't be able to extract them from there. And I have totally no idea of what your helper class does.

Comment: XML is naturally a **tree structure**. LINQ is great for working with data in that form. The helper extension methods I gave you along with standard LINQ methods make working with XML a breeze in C#/.NET. Take a look at the sample code I wrote and make sure you understand it. :)

Comment: Don't even know what linq is and how it works. Can't get anything out of it, sorry :S

Comment: @user2212907 [Getting Started with LINQ in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397933.aspx)

Comment: Many thanks I have a really huge amount of things to learn in these times, but I'll definitely take a look, sounds interesting.
By the way I really hate all these things and I find them stupid. Not anything agains your code or your guide. It's just that they keep adding layers and layers over a language that is humongously full of abstraction. Today to make a simple communication via web you have to use like 10 technologies mixed togheter. It's just plain stupid. I'll learn what I have to because I'm paid to make things possibly fast. But I'd rather write myself a XML parser, if it was for me.

Comment: @user2212907 If you try to write your own XML parser, you'll very quickly appreciate *just how easy it is* to simply grab the .NET one and go.

Comment: I've wrote some Regex parser for dates, times and various other things. A bit more irregular syntax doesn't scare me. I bet I would have been done in the time I spend understanding those XmlReaders or LINQ. But here at works I have to deal with multiple taks so I can't afford to write my own code and I have to use others code. That's the way it works, so I'll try my best to follow that LINQ guide or to do it with XmlReader (this last one probably will be what I'll have to do, no time to learn LINQ atm :/ )

Comment: Writing your own regex parsers for a learning experience I can imagine, but writing one yourself for anything professional is a waste of time imo.